# HttpClient can not get any response from a rest api that runs longer than an hour

Tags: rest, curl, httpclient

we have to consume a rest api that runs long time job. we use apache http cient to consume the api, but if the job runs longer than certain time, say one hour. our client just hangs there waiting for response even though the job has completed.

using curl to post to api seems to be fine with long run.

Answer (score 0):

i just found the solution with

```
        SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.custom().setSoKeepAlive(true).setSoTimeout(360000000).build(); //We need to set socket keep alive
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(360000000).build();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).
            setDefaultSocketConfig(socketConfig).build();
```

so by default curl keep socket alive, so i need to do the same in java. hopefully spring resttemplate has the same

Comment: my bad. the solution did not work. my app still runs to wait for response even though the job was done on the server side and a response was sent from the called api. so anyone out there can help out? suggestion